# Spark History Server ListBucket costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

We are using Spark history 3.2.1 to monitor our Spark applications.

We have thousands of daily jobs (running on Kubernetes) that writes event logs to S3 bucket (in a dedicated folder).

We are using history-server to analyze and compare completed jobs (incomplete running jobs never appeared in the UI but it's not a requirement now).

Recently I've noticed increase in our `ListBucket` API Operation in AWS billing cost explorer. This cost is higher than the cost of the `StandardStorage` (the price we pay for storing the data itself). It's up to few hundreds per month!

Running history-server with DEBUG log level exposed the "problem": [every 10s](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#spark-history-server-configuration-options) the the history-server list the bucket to get all logs and then it iterate over each folder to get it's content. So if I want to keep the last 10,000 jobs, I'll have to pay for 10,101 ListBucket requests every 10s!

Here is one example (out of the 10k) reproduced locally with `minio` as S3:

```
22/02/20 06:44:31 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-57 << "<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Name>local-audience</Name><Prefix>history-logs/eventlog_v2_spark-ffffdf5903c841259f28b53981746b76/</Prefix><KeyCount>2</KeyCount><MaxKeys>5000</MaxKeys><Delimiter>/</Delimiter><IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated><Contents><Key>history-logs/eventlog_v2_spark-ffffdf5903c841259f28b53981746b76/appstatus_spark-ffffdf5903c841259f28b53981746b76</Key><LastModified>2022-02-12T17:00:15.304Z</LastModified><ETag>&#34;d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&#34;</ETag><Size>0</Size><Owner><ID></ID><DisplayName></DisplayName></Owner><StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass></Contents><Contents><Key>history-logs/eventlog_v2_spark-ffffdf5903c841259f28b53981746b76/events_1_spark-ffffdf5903c841259f28b53981746b76</Key><LastModified>2022-02-12T17:00:15.136Z</LastModified><ETag>&#34;f91cc774d92c6f6c2ca4d0e1a1e76e13&#34;</ETag><Size>868837</Size><Owner><ID></ID><DisplayName></DisplayName></Owner><StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass></Contents></ListBucketResult>"
```

To ensure that the cost comes from history-server I turned it off for a day and there was no charge per `ListBucket` since then:

[image]

To mitigate the problem (because we still need the history-server), I can set the `spark.history.fs.update.interval` to higher number (such as 3600s or so). As we are checking the history-server once a day it is overkill and doesn't worth it (cost wise).

- Why does it scan the completed jobs every time (over and over again) and not only new jobs? is there a way to configure such behavior to avoid those `ListBucket` operations?
- If I care only for completed jobs, and assuming I can wait few minutes to see the list, is there a mode that can load the list only when I login to the UI? (rather than periodically doing it for nothing).

P.S - I'm using AWS [lifecycle rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to clean this folder every few few days (and not the server cleaning feature), by expiration objects after few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into this issue, I decided to stop using the "rolling" feature for now - as my application jobs are relatively small.
I removed the:

```
spark.eventLog.rolling.enabled: true
spark.eventLog.rolling.maxFileSize: 16m
```

from the `spark-submit` command and the cost is now back to normal...
I also wrote about it [here](https://itnext.io/wrong-spark-configuration-that-cost-us-3k-month-dc21f2a0a113).

@stevel thanks for your answer - I will try to contribute and fix that! :)

Answer (score 2):

treewalking in s3 is (a) expensive and (b) horribly slow, especially given that a deep tree scan exists. If you want to fix this *and can write scala code*, see if you can fix the server to switch to a deep listing by moving to `FileSystem.listFiles(path, true)`. Yes that involves coding, but the OSS community depends on everyone fixing their own personal issues and sharing the outcome